# Does the free surface of an ideal fluid in a cylindrical container rotating about its own axis for a paraboloid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

Does the free surface of an ideal fluid in a cylindrical container rotating about its own axis for a paraboloid?

It is just as the question asks. I've seen proofs that the above setup will create a paraboloid regardless of whether its an ideal or not.

I don't understand how the fluid would be affected by the rotation if it was ideal ( had no viscosity or friction ).

I just want this small doubt clarified before moving on.

P.S it's just the container that's rotating.

Comment: The liquid surface just orients itself in a position relative to the container.

Comment: The paraboloid is created due to the forces exerted by one layer on the second; it would not be created if there is no viscosity or friction.

Comment: Is the fluid rotating with the container, or is it just the container that is rotating?

Comment: @ChetMiller it's just the container that's rotating.

Comment: @StutiGupta Thanks

Comment: If the liquid is in is inviscid, even if the container rotates, the liquid cannot rotate.